# Is the support library provided in the android API the only means to include the newer android version features on older devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, porting

How google provides new android features to be available in older API levels via support librarys?

Comment: You can use `AppCompat` libraries for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about the two [picture-in-picture (PIP)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html) and [notifications channel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) references you have given 
Those are introduced in **Android O** and supposed to use from to above API level and won't support and unfortunately, there are no support libraries for this feature.
And for notifications you don't need channels it's another feature that Android has in **API 26** otherwise your notifications may be dropped by the system to avoid we use notifications channel otherwise for the back support we don't need such requirement.

But other features supported are available as [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)

Here is full [list](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0.html) of API and features introduced in Android O

Answer (score 2):

> i wonder if the newer android API features like picture in picture,notification channels can be used

For those features specifically? No. The vast majority of the work for those features is done outside of your app and any code that your app links to. That work is done by core OS processes.

> can i include the code to be used for this features to work in lower API versions

For those features specifically? No. Again, most of the work is done outside of your app.

*Some* features in newer Android versions can be "backported" to older versions. Mostly, that is for features that are purely implemented in code that your app links to. Google offers backports of some features as part of the Support Libraries. Other features might be backported by other developers, such as [my backport of Android 7.0's network security configuration](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity). Sometimes, the changes are just too complicated to backport, or nobody has "had the itch to scratch" to write the backport.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the feature,if it involves only software implementation then already many developers create ports or workarounds for such things using native components already available

This may differ case to case and depend on many factors including jvm limitations,etc